# IOError permission denied in AWS ubuntu

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04

I am facing a small issue with ubuntu on AWS. Every time I tried to install any library I am getting the same permission error.

I have attached the error pick with this question if someone can suggest me how to fix this error.

[Error Coming while install library](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s7Yla.png)

Comment: Please include things like error messages in the question itself instead of linking to a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

The command you are running needs root permissions. You need to use the `sudo` command. You didn't include your actual command in your question at all... but instead of `pip install whatever` it needs to be `sudo pip install whatever`.